# xacro: Substitution args not supported: cannot import name 'Log' from 'rosgraph_msgs.msg' in ubutnu desktop 22.04

Tags: gazebo, ros2, urdf, xacro, ros2-launch

I am very new to ROS2 and have only been practising for a few days so i am having a really tough time trying to find the solution.
I am on a dual boot PC with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04, and i am trying to run a .urdf.xacro file: https://github.com/eYantra-Robotics-Competition/eYRC-2023_Hologlyph_Bots/blob/main/hb_task1b_ws/src/hb_task_1b/urdf/hb_bot.urdf.xacro by running the command `xacro hb_bot.urdf.xacro`.

This xacro file is part of a ROS2 package where we are supposed to simulate a robot through Gazebo tool, and ultimately I am trying to run the command `ros2 launch hb_task_1b gazebo.launch.py`.

The error I get is:

```
substitution args not supported:  cannot import name 'Log' from 'rosgraph_msgs.msg' (/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosgraph_msgs/msg/__init__.py)

when processing file: hb_bot.urdf.xacro
```

When I tried to figure out which line of .xacro file was causing the problem, and using the error message to help, i figured wherever the code had substitutional args like `$(find something)/path/to/a/file`, this error was caused.

Some lines of code which caused this error are

`<xacro:include filename="$(find hb_task_1b)/urdf/materials.xacro"/>`,

`<mesh filename = "file://$(find hb_task_1b)/meshes/wheel.stl" scale="5 5 5"/>`,

`<mesh filename ="file://$(find hb_task_1b)/meshes/base.dae" scale="0.01  0.01 0.01"/>`,

etc.

I am NOT in a virtual environment, i have just installed Ubuntu and have not touched much of the software, so there is not much chance of files being corrupt.

What I have tried:
I have tried reinstalling xacro module, reinstalling pip3, deleting and again cloning the repo (which contains the .xacro file), and trying to run the file in different ways, through colcon builds, and each time I got the same error.
I tried to look at the file which is being referred to in the error message, and the _*init*_.py file contains a single line

`from rosgraph_msgs.msg._clock import Clock  # noqa: F401`,

and the file _clock.py file had some code from which I couldn't figure out anything with regards to how it cannot import `name 'Log' from 'rosgraph_msgs.msg'`.

Another xacro file, which does not use substitutional args, https://github.com/eYantra-Robotics-Competition/eYRC-2023_Hologlyph_Bots/blob/main/hb_task1b_ws/src/hb_task_1b/urdf/materials.xacro, runs completely fine thorugh the `xacro materials.xacro` command.

Any help on how to solve the issue, approach this issue, or where else can I look to resolve the issue would be helpful. Thank you.

PS: This is my first question on any of the stack exchange platforms and I have tried to follow all the etiquettes, but like most firsts, this is not perfect and any improvements would be welcome :)